# Not able to invalidate a query upon successful mutation in React Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am developing a MERN stack app & I am using **React Query** for managing server state.

After I log in, I can create a ticket using a form as shown below:

[image]

After filling in the details, when I click on the `Create Ticket` button, I do two things:

- I invalidate the query with the key `tickets` (`queryClient.invalidateQueries("tickets")`), so that the "/tickets" route has the latest list of tickets. *My understanding here is that invalidating a query will make the query refetch in the background.*

```
export const usePostTicket = (setTicketError) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  return useMutation(
    (ticketData) => {
      axios.post("/api/users/tickets/create", ticketData);
    },
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        navigate("/tickets");
        queryClient.invalidateQueries("tickets");
      },
      onError: ({ message }) => {
        setTicketError(message);
      },
    }
  );
};
```

- And, I get redirected to the `tickets` page (`navigate("/tickets")`). This is the page where I should be able to see all my tickets, including the newly created ticket.

However, I don't see any tickets on the page.

[image]

This means that the query with the key `tickets` is not getting refetched in the background.

**ONLY when I refocus on the window**, I see all the tickets on the page.

[image]

**QUESTION: Why is the tickets query not getting refetched in the background?**

**EDIT-1**
The following is my custom hook that fetches all the tickets:

```
export const useGetTickets = () => {
  const response = useQuery(["tickets"], async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/users/tickets");
    return data;
  });

  return response;
};
```

And I am using version 4 of React Query

Comment: How does your useQuery looks like? Also, are you using v3 or v4 lib version?

Comment: Please see Edit-1

Comment: I think in version 4 you need to always pass keys as an array:         `queryClient.invalidateQueries(["tickets"])`. Not quite sure that it will help, but other than that your code looks fine

Comment: No, that's not the case. And the funny thing is the query gets refetched sometimes. Other times, I have to refocus on the window. It's weird. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Can you please take a look here: https://github.com/sundaray/supportdesk.git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mutation function doesn't return anything:

```
(ticketData) => {
  axios.post("/api/users/tickets/create", ticketData);
},
```

That will make the mutation succeed right away, before the request has finished. Then, the invalidation will run instantly, and it will likely fetch the old data, or you'll have a race condition.

To fix this, return the promise from your mutation function:

```
(ticketData) => {
  return axios.post("/api/users/tickets/create", ticketData);
},
```

Comment: If the user made a typo please try to make a comment about it and suggest to close the question with `A community-specific reason` -> `It was a typo` option. There is no value in such answers at all.

Comment: I appreciate this suggestion, but this is not a "typo". I can't know if OP forgot to add `return`, or if they thought it doesn't matter if the promise is returned from the function. This is behaviour specific to react-query that your mutation function has to return a promise. In fact, it might work well in some cases if you don't return the promise. But you'll be subject to race conditions, which I also outlined in the answer.